# Import Pico CSS from node into custom SCSS file

Tags: docker, npm, sass

I have a Docker build process where SCSS is compiled to build a website. I want to base my CSS on Pico CSS. I'm not using Webpack or anything like that, just plain SCSS. I'm only using Node to install Pico.

Supposedly, I can include Pico CSS with the following directive:

```scss
@import "@picocss/pico/scss/pico";
```

However, it appears that the SCSS processor doesn't recognise it:

```
#0 0.370 Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
#0 0.370   ╷
#0 0.370 1 │ @import "@picocss/pico/scss/pico";
#0 0.370   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.370   ╵
#0 0.370   main.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

It seems that I'm having trouble including Pico CSS because it gets installed by Node.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```bash
FROM node:19-alpine as scss_build
WORKDIR /scss

# Install requirements
RUN npm install sass @picocss/pico

# Add SCSS
COPY static/scss .

# Build
RUN npx sass --style=compressed main.scss /build.css

# (Run the rest of the build)
```

I've tried using the trick mentioned in various places online to add a tilde in front of the import:

```scss
/* None of these work! */
@import "@picocss/pico/scss/pico";
@import "~@picocss/pico/scss/pico";
@import "~picocss/pico/scss/pico";
```